# What's the username and password for beeline

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I am using cloudera VM and I want to connect to beeline but it's asking for username and password when i am leaving empty, it's not connecting. Can someone tell me the username and password.

!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/:
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/:
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (state=08S01,code=0)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/ (closed)>

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ beeline
2019-10-09 17:06:46,217 WARN [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present. Continuing without it.
Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.7.0 by Apache Hive
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/
scan complete in 5ms
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/: hadoop
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/:
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (state=08S01,code=0)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/ (closed)>

Can someone know the username and password to login to beeline. I have checked hive metastore and hive server2. it's working :-

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service hive-metastore status
Hive Metastore is running

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service hive-server2 status
Hive Server2 is running [ OK ]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. My Namenode was in safe mode. So i have turned off safe mode by using :- hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave

Answer (score 0):

You can use "beeline -u jdbc:hive2://"

It will connect to hive2. This is the best way to talk to hive using beeline. You don't need to specify any other things. Please let me know if this works for all who wants to use hive through beeline command. Please check the link [beeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdHS7.jpg)